# Fetch WordPress API call :: how to get it to actually display on the page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch, wordpress-rest-api

https://codepen.io/Mortiferr/pen/XYNLpK?editors=1011

I'm trying to get the posts to display here and I cannot seem to make it work. If I console.log `data[0].title` it works and gives the data I ask for. But when I try and display it on the page...no dice. See codepen for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `data.title` is an object with `rendered` inside.

`data[0].title.rendered` will do the work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  fetch('https://www.perfectimprints.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Here's a list of repos!
    $("#postTitle").append(data[0].title.rendered);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="postDate"></div>
<div id="postTitle"></div>
```

Comment: You are the best. Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: next time you can try `console.log(data)` and check it in devtools. It will show you how it looks.